# Making a CFG for a^i b^j c^k such that i+j = 3k

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, pushdown-automata

I have the language $L = \{a^i b^j c^k \mid i+j=3k\}$, however I am struggling to convert it to a CFG.

I have made it into a PDA fairly easily, its just now getting this to the CFG which is the issue.

I have thought about dividing it into 3 cases then taking the union of them for example:

$i=0, j=3k$

$i=3k, j=0$

But this still hasn't gotten me very far

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure whether it is a good idea to actually provide the grammar here in an answer but since the grammar is actually fairly easy I cannot see which details I could hide in a hint, so here it is:

$G = (\{S, A\}, \{a, b, c\}, P, S)$ with 
$$
P = \{S \to aaaSc \mid aabAc \mid abbAc \mid bbbAc \mid \varepsilon, A \to bbbAc \mid \varepsilon\}.$$
You start by adding three $a$s for each $c$, after finitely many (possibly 0) applications of the first rule, you start creating three $b$s for each $c$ but one time you may actually add 2 $a$s, 1 $b$ for one $c$ or 1 $a$, 2 $b$s for one $c$ (2nd and 3rd rule, respectively).

Answer (score 0):

$L = \{a^i b^j c^k \mid i+j=3k\}$. You need to match up two counts; this can only be done by having a middle-recursive set of rules that generate both parts in correct proportions. All you need is $X \Rightarrow^+ \alpha X \beta$, with $\alpha$ generating 3 $a$s and $b$s, $\beta$ generating 3 $c$s.  This can be a single rule, and $X$ can just be the start symbol $S$, so let's start with

$S \rightarrow\epsilon \mid T S ccc$

$T$ must generate $a^ib^{3-i}$ for all $i$, a finite language, so we can just have a rule for each member:

$T \rightarrow aaa \mid aab \mid abb \mid bbb$

We can substitute $T$ into the rule for $S$ to arrive at PHPNick's answer.